# iText 7 C# : Making an Image Less Blurry

Tags: c#, windows, charts, itext

I am trying to add a Generated Windows chart to an iText Table and then put this table in a PDF file. The said table is 2 columns wide in a page set in landscape. I was able to to do this, but the problem is that when the file is generated, the image is blurry, especially the text. When I save the image on hard drive, it's not blurry whatsoever.

[image: Example of the image]

Here is the method I use to convert the Windows chart to an iText image:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts a Windows chart to an iText image
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="chart">The Windows chart</param>
        /// <returns>The converted iText image</returns>
        private static Image ConvertChartToiTextImage(Chart chart)
        {
            System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(chart.Width, chart.Height);
            bmp.SetResolution(600, 600);
            
            chart.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, chart.Width, chart.Height));
            ImageCodecInfo pngEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Png);
            EncoderParameters encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            ImageData data = null;
            
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bmp.Save(stream, pngEncoder, encoderParameters);
                data = ImageDataFactory.Create(stream.ToArray());
                data.SetDpi(600, 600);
                data.SetInterpolation(false);
            }
            Image image = new Image(data);
            return image;
        }

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        { 
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders(); 
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs) 
            { 
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid) 
                { 
                    return codec; 
                } 
            } 
            return null;
        }
```

I tried to set the width and the height of the chart directly so that it fits in the table, but it didn't help with the quality of the image. The rest of my attempts are in the code I shared and the image is the result it gave.

Comment: Have you tried to save the Image as PNG instead of JPEG? Quality 100 is still lossy (that happens in PhotoShop, too. You have to manually specify 12 instead of the default maximum quality 10, otherwise you don't get a loss-less interpolation) -- Setting the DPI resolution descriptor to a value that is higher than the original, may have effects when the Image is rendered in specific contexts (because it might be enlarged)

Comment: @Jimi The image is already PNG. I set the quality up to a 1000 and it didn't change anything. If it can help, when I save the image in hard drive, it's not blurry. The problem seems to be when I place it in the pdf file.

Comment: Hmm, I was mislead because you wrote `jpegEncoder` and you're using an Encoder to set the quality. PNG images don't have a *quality* setting. A PDF doesn't have DPI definition either, it depends on where it's rendered. Set the DPI of the image to 72 (default in this context), or your Screen's DPI value. Try also an uncompressed (or LZW compressed) TIFF image. I doubt it will render better than a PNG, though

Comment: Please share the generated pdf for analysis.